# Python How to save image to different directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image

files = glob.glob('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/*.jpg')

for f in files:
    img = Image.open(f)
    img_resize = img.resize((int(img.width / 2), int(img.height / 2)))
    title, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    img_resize.save(title + '_half' + ext)
```

**I want to save new images to**

```
"/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/11/*.jpg"
```

**Not**

```
"/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/*.jpg"
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your processed images to your preferred directory (`/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/11/*.jpg`) by changing the parameter for `img_resize.save()` there.

Assuming that you still want to save the processed image with `_half` suffix in its filename. So the final code goes here:

```py
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image

files = glob.glob('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/*.jpg')
DESTINATION_PATH = '/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crop001/1/11/'  # The preferred path for saving the processed image

for f in files:
    img = Image.open(f)
    img_resize = img.resize((int(img.width / 2), int(img.height / 2)))

    base_filename = os.path.basename(f)
    title, ext = os.path.splitext(base_filename)
    final_filepath = os.path.join(DESTINATION_PATH, title + '_half' + ext)

    img_resize.save(final_filepath)
```

All of the function's docs I used here can be found here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html